# PHP - Registerform says no error but dosent save in DB

Tags: php, mysql

I have one registerform.. when I fill it out, it dosent save in the DB. But the error only says: There is one error saving. I am new to PHP , but I am like 3 hours now trying to find the error.. Hope someone can help me here! Thank you!

```html
<?php 
session_start();
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', 'root', '');
?>
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head>
  <title>Registrierung</title> 
</head> 
<body>
 
<?php
$showFormular = true; //Variable ob das Registrierungsformular anezeigt werden soll
 
if(isset($_GET['register'])) {
 $error = false;
 $email = $_POST['email'];
 $passwort = $_POST['passwort'];
 $passwort1 = $_POST['passwort1'];
 $hotelname = $_POST['hotelname'];
 $ansprech = $_POST['ansprech'];
 $telefon = $_POST['telefon'];
  
 if(!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
 echo 'Bitte eine gültige E-Mail-Adresse eingeben<br>';
 $error = true;
 } 
 if(strlen($passwort) == 0) {
 echo 'Bitte ein Passwort angeben<br>';
 $error = true;
 }
 if($passwort != $passwort1) {
 echo 'Die Passwörter müssen übereinstimmen<br>';
 $error = true;
 }
 
 //Überprüfe, dass die E-Mail-Adresse noch nicht registriert wurde
 if(!$error) { 
 $statement = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = :email");
 $result = $statement->execute(array('email' => $email));
 $user = $statement->fetch();
 
 if($user !== false) {
 echo 'Diese E-Mail-Adresse ist bereits vergeben<br>';
 $error = true;
 } 
 }
 
 //Keine Fehler, wir können den Nutzer registrieren
 if(!$error) { 
 $passwort_hash = password_hash($passwort, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
 
 $statement = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO users (email, passwort, hotelname, ansprech, telefon) VALUES (:email, :passwort, :hotelname, :ansprech, :telefon;)");
 $result = $statement->execute(array('email' => $email, 'passwort' => $passwort_hash, 'hotelname' => $hotelname, 'ansprech' => $ansprech, 'telefon' => $telefon));
 
 if($result) { 
 echo 'Du wurdest erfolgreich registriert. <a href="login.php">Zum Login</a>';
 $showFormular = false;
 } else {
 echo 'Beim Abspeichern ist leider ein Fehler aufgetreten<br>';
 }
 } 
}
 
if($showFormular) {
?>
<form action="?register=1" method="post">
<form class="form-horizontal">
    <fieldset>

        <!-- Form Name -->
        <legend>Form Name</legend>
        <!-- Text input-->
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="Hotelname">Hotelname</label>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <input name="hotelname" class="form-control input-md" id="hotelname" required="" type="text" placeholder="Hotelname">

            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Text input-->
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="Ansprechpartner">Ansprechpartner</label>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <input name="ansprech" class="form-control input-md" id="ansprech" required="" type="text" placeholder="Ansprechpartner">

            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Text input-->
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="Email">Email</label>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <input name="email" class="form-control input-md" id="email" required="" type="text" placeholder="Email-Adresse">

            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Text input-->
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="Telefon">Telefon</label>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <input name="telefon" class="form-control input-md" id="telefon" required="" type="text" placeholder="Telefonnummer">

            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Password input-->
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="passwort">Passwort</label>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <input name="passwort" class="form-control input-md" id="passwort" required="" type="password" placeholder="Passwort">

            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Password input-->
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="passwort1">Passwort Wiederholen</label>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <input name="passwort1" class="form-control input-md" id="passwort1" required="" type="password" placeholder="Passwort Wiederholen">

            </div>
        </div>

    </fieldset>
    <input type="submit" value="Abschicken">
</form>
        

<?php
} //Ende von if($showFormular)
?>
 
</body>
```

After Submitting only error is:
Saving error , but not showing me what line or something.

Comment: why do you have two opening form tags?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the colons :

```
$result = $statement->execute(array(':email' => $email));
```

and

```
$result = $statement->execute(array(':email' => $email, ':passwort' => $passwort_hash, ':hotelname' => $hotelname, ':ansprech' => $ansprech, ':telefon' => $telefon));
```

And as pointed by @user2486, there is an extra `;` in `:telefon;` :

```
 $statement = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO users (email, passwort, hotelname, ansprech, telefon) VALUES (:email, :passwort, :hotelname, :ansprech, :telefon)");
```

Comment: Also there is extra `;` here `:telefon;`

Comment: @user2486 You're right. I'll add in the anwser. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry after hours I think I am blind :D ... I have it like you post?

Comment: @Jerome Accept the anwser (the green check) to mark your question as closed. Thanks.

Comment: THANKS! Works.. So much hours for so small error.. Why PHP IDE dosent Show it as error :(